# new RecursiveIteratorIterator in Laravels custom model

Tags: recursion, model, laravel-4

I try to call inside of my laravel models method PHP's `RecursiveIteratorIterator` as follows

```
$columns = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($feeds));
```

but I get

```
Class 'App\Models\RecursiveIteratorIterator' not found
```

How do I include in my Model normally should be accessible

**Found it**

```
use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;
use \RecursiveArrayIterator;
```

Comment: It would be good if you post your finding as an answer and accept that. So that in future some can reach there easly

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($PATH)) as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br>";
}
```